# orm_execute_state does not reflect an update occurring on the ORM object within Session listener

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have the following session listener:

```python
@event.listens_for(Session, "do_orm_execute")
def do_orm_execute(orm_execute_state):
    print('is_update', orm_execute_state.is_update)
```

`is_update` always returns `False`, even if I make changes to the ORM Object.

When I update a user instance to have a new name, for instance:

```python
user = session.get(User,'some_id')
user.name = "New and updated name"
session.commit()
session.execute()
```

The new name gets stored in the database, the `do_orm_execute` gets called and `orm_execute_state.is_select` returns `True`. However, for some reason `orm_execute_state.is_update` returns `False`.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

session.execute() is not executing the user.name update in your example.

That kind of update is flushed to the db on session.commit().  The event can be seen with [persistence events](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_events.html#persistence-events) hooks.

> The flush is where all the decisions are made about pending changes to
> objects and are then emitted out to the database in the form of INSERT,
> UPDATE, and DELETE statements

The session.get(User, id) will fire a 'do_orm_execute' event with is_select=True because it needs to get the obj from the db into the session mapper now, as you need it.

> Session.get() is special in that it provides direct access to the
> identity map of the Session. If the given primary key identifier is
> present in the local identity map, the object is returned directly from
> this collection and no SQL is emitted, unless the object has been marked
> fully expired. If not present, a SELECT is performed in order to locate
> the object.
> https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.get

The session "manages persistence operations for ORM-mapped objects" while the ORMExecuteState executes a sql statement.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_api.html#session-and-sessionmaker

You see them both happening in your example behind the scenes.  I didn't look into the code, so I'm not sure why the events are separated.